# How can I extend Magento to override payment info validation?

Tags: validation, magento, checkout, onepage-checkout

I am building a Magento extension to handle Level 3 payments through PayTrace's payment gateway. This particular payment method allows customers to select a saved credit card via Paytrace's customer info management (tokenized saved cards) instead of entering credit card information.

I can use Prototype, I understand how to add validation classes to the HTML in the template.

But the other validation is stumping me. I want to be able to submit the payment card's Paytrace id and not a credit card # and expiration date. When I add a select to the template and submit the selected card id, it pops up a javascript alert telling me "Incorrect credit card expiration date".

There is a request to "/checkout/onepage/savePayment" when I click "continue" that comes back with json {"error":"Incorrect credit card expiration date."} so this validation appears to occur via PHP on the server side.

My question here is "how do I extend Magento to override the server side one page checkout validation for payment?"

Comment: Have you already created a new payment method model in your extension?

Comment: Yes, the extension's model extends Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet

Comment: it sounds like you might need to implement a new payment method as well for the token setup that implements `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract`. Right now it sounds like you are still using `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc` whose `validate()` method expects credit card data.

Comment: It looks like you're right, @fantasticrice. I appreciate the suggestion, thank you.